# SWITCH Function with multiple hits - Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I recently started using Power BI a month ago. I'm currently trying to use SWITCH to sort through a column of text. The main problem that I am running into is that when a row has multiple words that satisfy the criteria for a case that I've coded for, the output column only contains the first case being satisfied, instead of all of the cases being satisfied.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
SWITCH Hits Test =
SWITCH(
TRUE(),
CONTAINSSTRING('SWITCH Test'[Raw Data], "cat"), "cat",
CONTAINSSTRING('SWITCH Test'[Raw Data], "dog"), "dog",
CONTAINSSTRING('SWITCH Test'[Raw Data], "fox"), "fox",
"Not Target")
```

And here's what my table looks like:

| Raw Data | SWITCH Hits Test | Ideal Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dog cat | cat | cat, dog |
| dog dog | dog | dog |
| dog fox | dog | dog, fox |
| cat dog | cat | cat, dog |
| cat cat | cat | cat |
| cat fox | cat | cat, fox |
| test | Not Target | Not Target |

The solution that I've come up with is to make separate columns for each SWITCH case, but I was wondering if there was another workaround/potential function I could use before doing this as it seems time intensive for larger SWITCH functions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Add a custom column:

```
let
a={"cat", "dog", "fox"},
b =  List.Distinct(  List.RemoveNulls( Text.Split( Text.Trim( [Raw Data]), " "))),
c = List.Intersect({a,b}),
d = Text.Combine(c, ", ")
in if List.IsEmpty(c) then "Not Target" else d
```

Full code

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WSslPV0hOLFFQ0lFCUDoKQGGlWB2INAgDxREUXCYtvwJVRgckBJYGGQYVx2YuSAzDWrgM1FxkjTBzS1KLwYJ++SUKIYlF6aloPKXYWAA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Raw Data" = _t, #"SWITCH Hits Test" = _t, #"Ideal Result" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Raw Data", type text}, {"SWITCH Hits Test", type text}, {"Ideal Result", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each let
a={"cat", "dog", "fox"},
b =  List.Distinct(  List.RemoveNulls( Text.Split( Text.Trim( [Raw Data]), " "))),
c = List.Intersect({a,b}),
d = Text.Combine(c, ", ")
in if List.IsEmpty(c) then "Not Target" else d)
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked perfectly! I was also wondering: let's say I want to classify the text using themes (example: if the string contains "cat" AND "dog", then return "domestic pet"); is this something I could tweak your above solution to inlcude by any chance? Or would I have to make a separate column for it.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Ask a new question with sample data and expected results and we can take a look.